# How to display image that has shown in superdirectory PHP file through subdirectory PHP file?

Tags: php, html, image, directory

I want to show image through header.php file that is the same level directory with image file.

In my header.php use **< img src="image.jpg">** to display image,
but my index.php is subdirectory and use **include('../header.php');**.

```
=== image.jpg
=== header.php
=== new folder
====== index.php
```

Yeah, the image will not show this way.
because in index.php will also have **< img src="image.jpg">** like header.php that I included.

Are there anyway showing image from index.php through header.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont have  to display image both in header.php and index.php just set

```
<img src="../image.jpg">
```

Butt if you  want to display image in header.php and index.php too,

i think this may help:

```
<img src="/your_website_name/image.jpg">
```

so no matter ,where you are -> in header.php or in index.php  you can use same code:

```
<img src="/your_website_name/image.jpg">
```

or using php

```
<img src="/<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/image.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

It includes header page but it looks for image in index page direcory, So Use "../image.jpg".